# datepicker in anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I want to display datepicker in anchor tag.Now datepicker shows onclick.but I doesn't hide.I want to do this in toggle effect.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a").click(function(){
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
}); 
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="test">click here</a>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
 </html>
```

I want to display datepicker When i click 'click here' text and hide datepicker div when i click text 2nd time. I want to display datepicker in toggele effect of click me.

Comment: you have an inline datepicker... when do you want to hide it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think 1 option is to destroy the datepicker once a date is selected.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $dp = $("#datepicker");
  $(".aastext").click(function() {
    if ($dp.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
      $dp.datepicker("destroy");
    } else {
      $dp.datepicker({
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $dp.datepicker("destroy");
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<a class="aastext">click here</a>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: If datepicker show it will disappear after i click 'click here' and vice versa

Comment: year and month display in date picker is collapsed.How to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

This could help you:

```
var $dp = $( "#datepicker" );  
$dp.datepicker().hide();

$("a").click(function(event){        
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($dp.is(':hidden')) {
        $dp.show();
    }else{
        $dp.hide();
    }
});
```

This will initialitze the datepicker only once and will hide it immediatly.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pbsoobvp/)

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the datepicker visibility programmatically on anchor and document click.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("a").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#datepicker").toggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        $("#datepicker").hide();
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ugf9ncgh/